# help with integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let $P(R)=e^R\cdot\int_R^{\infty}F(z)e^{-z}dz=\int_0^{\infty}F(R+z)e^{-z}dz$. Is it true that $P(R) \geq 0$ for all $R$ implies $F(z) \geq 0$ for all $z$?

In my case, $F(z)$ is a difference of CDF functions, in particular, I can assume that that $|F(z)|\leq1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. A small negative bump at some place can be compensated by positive values later.

Take for example

$$F(z) = \begin{cases}0 &, z \leqslant 0\\ -z &, 0 < z \leqslant \varepsilon\\
z - 2\varepsilon &, \varepsilon < z \leqslant 10\varepsilon\\ 8\varepsilon e^{10\varepsilon-z}&, 10\varepsilon < z,\end{cases}$$

where $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{20}$. Then

$$A(R) = \int_R^\infty F(z)e^{-z}\,dz$$

is constant for $R < 0$, positive for $R \geqslant 2\varepsilon$, and increasing on $[0,2\varepsilon]$, so it suffices to see that $A(0) > 0$ in order to deduce that $P(R) = e^R\cdot A(R)$ is always positive. We can easily estimate

$$\int_0^{2\varepsilon} F(z)e^{-z}\,dz > \int_0^{2\varepsilon} F(z)\,dz = -\varepsilon^2,$$

and

$$\int_{2\varepsilon}^\infty F(z)e^{-z}\,dz > e^{-10\varepsilon}\int_{2\varepsilon}^{10\varepsilon} F(z)\,dz = 32\varepsilon^2e^{-10\varepsilon},$$

so the integral is positive for all $R$.